# at that time or of that time?

Tags: grammar, collocations, sentence

Hello in the following sentence can the preposition "of" work?
Diamond rings date back to the Roman empire in 300BC. Diamonds ( ) that time were uncut and quite different.
Is "at that time" the only collocation or can possessive be used and correct? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

To the extent the preposition makes any difference in OP's context (and it's a *tiny* difference that wouldn't always be intended / understood by writer / reader anyway), it's that...

> 1: *Diamonds **of** that time*

...is better suited to contexts where ***those diamonds still exist***, and can be meaningfully distinguished from *other* diamonds ("current" diamonds, or diamonds from other periods in history). Correspondingly,...

> 2: *Diamonds **at** that time*

...works better if the context is focused on ***those diamonds in the past*** (discussing how they were cut or set, for example, assuming such things were done differently back then).

---

Hence, because OP's context continues with past tense ***...were** quite different*, the preferred preposition is ***at***.

We're talking about ***those** diamonds **as they were then***, not ***these** diamonds that **came from that time***. It would be different if we were talking about the *current value* of, say, *Roman coins **of** that time.*

Answer (score 2):

You want to choose between the following.

1. At that time diamonds were uncut.
2. Diamonds of that time were uncut.

Choice 1 tells us what was happening then. Choice 2 tells us about diamonds during that time.

For choice 1 the modifier is to the time, it is *that* time. In choice 2 it is to the diamonds. They are diamonds *of that time.*